# DIR command lists 1 then 100

Tags: cmd, directory

When I use the `dir` command with folders ordered 1-100 or more, this is the result:

```
1
100
101
...
2
200
201
...
```

Because of this I have to scroll/look down to see the other numbers. And no, I'm not gonna rename them to `001`, `002` [...] `057`, etc.

How do I order the numbers correctly within the `dir` command without using `for` or any others?

Comment: You don't. `Dir` has no functionality for "natural sort order"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not like it, and it may not be the quickest of methods, but it's certainly simple, despite the fact you requested not to use `for`:

```bash
For /L %G In (1,1,999) Do @Dir /B /A:D | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /X "%G"
```

Or the lazier, *(not recommended)*, route:

```bash
for /l %g in (1 1 999)do @dir/b/ad|findstr/x %g
```

---

Without the `for` loop you'd need to get a little more creative, but I suppose technically the `findstr` utility would be classed as 'others' and also excluded in your question:

Example using simple command joining:

```bash
Dir /B /A:D /O:N "?" | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /X /C:"[123456789]" & Dir /B /A:D /O:N "??" | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /X /C:"[123456789][0123456789]" & Dir /B /A:D /O:N "???" | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /X /C:"[123456789][0123456789][0123456789]"
```

And, of course the lazier, *(not recommended)*, route:

```bash
dir/b/ad/on ?|findstr/rxc:[1-9]&dir/b/ad/on ??|findstr/rxc:[1-9][0-9]&dir/b/ad/on ???|findstr/rxc:[1-9][0-9][0-9]
```

---

If neither of the above ideas are acceptable due to your exclusions of 'for' and 'others', then the answer is simple. It cannot be done.

Comment: Well, `findstr` is acceptable. And maybe I can accept the `for` method, given its short length. With "`for` or others" I was asking if there was a switch to change the order and order the folder names correctly.